# Python curses ERR pipeline

Tags: python, continuous-integration, pipeline, curses

I would like to reproduce the result of a curses python script when a key is pressed for a pipeline.

Let's consider the following python script:

```py
import curses

class Sf:
    def __init__(self):

        self.window = curses.initscr()
        curses.start_color()
        curses.use_default_colors()
        curses.noecho()
        curses.curs_set(False)
        self.window.keypad(True)
        self.window.addstr(0, 1, "Test")
        while True:
            key = self.window.getch()
            if key == ord("q"):
                self.window.keypad(False)
                curses.nocbreak()
                curses.echo()
                curses.endwin()
                break

sf = Sf()
```

To inject the key press I am using `subprocess.run`:

```py
>>> from subprocess import run
>>> run(["python", "example.py"], input="q", encoding="ASCII", capture_output=True, env={"TERM": "xterm-256color"})
CompletedProcess(args=['python', 'example.py'], returncode=1, stdout='\x1b[?1049h\x1b[22;0;0t\x1b[1;24r\x1b(B\x1b[m\x1b[4l\x1b[?7h\x1b[39;49m\x1b[?25l\x1b[?1h\x1b=\x1b[39;49m\x1b(B\x1b[m\x1b[H\x1b[2J Test\x1b[?1l\x1b>', stderr='Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File "example.py", line 26, in <module>\n    sf = Sf()\n  File "example.py", line 21, in __init__\n    curses.nocbreak()\n_curses.error: nocbreak() returned ERR\n'
```

Any idea about the curses error?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

curses reads from terminals; a pipe is not a tty.

The manual page for [`nocbreak`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_inopts.3x.html#h3-cbreak_nocbreak) says

> Normally, the *tty* driver buffers typed characters until  a  newline  or
> carriage  return  is typed.  The **`cbreak`** routine disables line buffering
> and erase/kill character-processing (interrupt and flow control characters  are  unaffected), making characters typed by the user immediately
> available to the program.  The **`nocbreak`** routine returns the terminal to
> normal (cooked) mode.

The error message refers to the code returned by [`nocbreak`](https://github.com/ThomasDickey/ncurses-snapshots/blob/ba41a99b24e4ca0fca686780f80bf53b38bc16f3/ncurses/tinfo/lib_raw.c#L277), which happens because the mode-change doesn't work for pipes.  So ncurses returns [`ERR`](https://github.com/ThomasDickey/ncurses-snapshots/blob/ba41a99b24e4ca0fca686780f80bf53b38bc16f3/ncurses/tinfo/lib_ttyflags.c#L118).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is there a way to emulate a terminal?

Answer (score 0):

Pexpect is what I was looking for.